# How do I fetch and process 2 records then consecutive pair?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to proces records one by one comparing each to its prior then move to next and do the same until last record.

Structure to proces

```
id  dat        qty  dif
1   2019-05-01  2   NULL
2   2019-05-01  6   NULL
3   2019-05-01  3   NULL
1   2019-05-02  4   NULL
2   2019-05-02  7   NULL
3   2019-05-02  5   NULL
```

Expected result

```
id  dat        qty  dif
1   2019-05-01  2   0
1   2019-05-02  4   2
2   2019-05-01  6   0
2   2019-05-02  7   1
3   2019-05-01  3   0
3   2019-05-02  5   2
```

For id =1 and dat= '2019-05-01' dif = (2 - 0) which is current qty minus prior qty
For id =1 and dat= '2019-05-02' dif = (4 - 2)

Do I need scrollable cursor ? How to get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2008 does not support `LAG`, we can try simulating it using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    id,
    dat,
    qty,
    qty - COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 t2.qty FROM yourTable t2
           WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.dat < t1.dat
           ORDER BY t2.dat DESC), t1.qty) AS dif
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    id, dat;
```

[image]

### Demo